# How do I identify only the running workflow instances of a list item in Sharepoint Online CSOM

Tags: sharepoint-online, workflow, csom, workflow-manager

I am able to get all the workflows associated with a list item. But it looks like only one of the workflows can be running for the list item in this list. I want to be able to figure out which is the running workflow. This is the code snippet with which I am displaying all the properties of a WorkflowInstance.

```
int listItemId = 6326;
var workflowInstances = wfInstanceService.EnumerateInstancesForListItem(listGUID, listItemId);
clientContext.Load(workflowInstances);
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
foreach (var instance in workflowInstances)
{
    PrintText("Instance ID: " + instance.Id.ToString(), sw);
    PrintText("Status: " + instance.Status.ToString(), sw);
    PrintText("Creation time: " + instance.InstanceCreated.ToString(), sw);
    PrintText("Last updated time: " + instance.LastUpdated.ToString(), sw);
    PrintText("User status: " + instance.UserStatus, sw);

    IDictionary<string, string> props = instance.Properties;
    foreach(KeyValuePair<string, string> kvp in props)
    {
        PrintText(kvp.Key+": "+kvp.Value, sw);
    }

    PrintText("---------", sw);
}
```

Say there are 5 workflows associated with the list item 6326, I see all the details printing properly. But, I am not able to find out which one is running with all the data that I'm printing above. (PrintText function is essentially a Console.WriteLine). In my list items I cannot assume that the workflow that was created most recent is the running one too.

Link to where I found these built in functions: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/working-with-the-sharepoint-workflow-services-client-side-object-model

How do I determine which one is running?

Comment: Finished workflows should have the value of Status field set to "Completed".

Answer (score 0):

Each Workflow Instance should have a status which will be a value in the WorkflowStatus enumeration: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.workflowservices.workflowstatus.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

To get the running workflow instances, you could check for the "Started" status:

```
string siteUrl = "https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/intranet";
string userName = "admin@tenant.onmicrosoft.com";
string password = "adminpassword";
string listTitle = "MyList";
string workflowName = "MyWorkflow";
var workflowStatus = WorkflowStatus.Started;
var clientContext = GetClientContext(siteUrl, userName, password);
Web web = clientContext.Web;
Guid listGUID= GetListGUID(clientContext, listTitle);

//Get the workflow subscription (workflow definition)
var wfServicesManager = new WorkflowServicesManager(clientContext, web);
var wfSubscriptionService = wfServicesManager.GetWorkflowSubscriptionService();
var wfSubscriptions = wfSubscriptionService.EnumerateSubscriptionsByList(listGUID);
clientContext.Load(wfSubscriptions, wfSubs => wfSubs.Where(wfSub => wfSub.Name == workflowName));
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
var wfSubscription = wfSubscriptions.First();

//Get the workflow instances
var wfInstanceService = wfServicesManager.GetWorkflowInstanceService();
var wfInstanceCollection = wfInstanceService.Enumerate(wfSubscription);
clientContext.Load(wfInstanceCollection, wfInstances => wfInstances.Where(wfI => wfI.Status == workflowStatus));
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

//List all instances with the selected status. 
foreach (var wfInstance in wfInstanceCollection)
{
    Console.WriteLine(wfInstance.Properties["Microsoft.SharePoint.ActivationProperties.CurrentItemUrl"]);
}
```

I have blogged about get all workflow instances with a specific status here: https://www.vrdmn.com/2016/09/get-all-suspended-or-terminated.html